# Find the optimal number of photos of infinite cylinder.

Tags: trigonometry, metric-spaces, angle

I need to solve the following problem :

Suppose I have a perfectly cylindrical object with diameter `D`, and a infinite height, placed on a normal surface. I have a camera, with angular aperture `alpha` , and I position myself in a distance $d$, always pointing the camera normally to the center of the facing cylinder.

Considering the camera is always at a fixed height, and that the distance you will be from the cylinder will always be a fixed distance d, although you can walk radially around the cylinder, what is the maximum number of n photos you can take with the camera, before any photos overlap? Also $d < D$.

I have the following answer until now :

$$n= \frac{360}{2( \pi - \alpha - \arcsin ( (\frac{D+2d}{D})  \sin (\alpha) ))} $$

I modeled the problem to a Side Side Angle triangle problem and found the internal angle of the arc photographed by the camera.

But this answer doesn't seem to make sense - a bigger distance from the cylinder doesn't reduce the number of photos required.

**What is the maximum number of $n$ photos you can take with the camera, at fixed distance $d$, of cylinder of diameter $D$, before any photos overlap?**

Comment: The answer ought to have a piecewise definition somewhere: Close to the cylinder, your aperture angle $\alpha$ will determine how much of the cylinder you can fit in a singe image; as you move away, $\alpha$ stops being relevant because the horizons are less than $\alpha$ apart. (In particular, what happens to your formula when the input to $\arcsin$ becomes greater than $1$?)

Comment: Isn't the answer always 2 if $D \leq 2d\tan{\theta \over 2}$? I'm fairly sure you need to split up your function into cases.

Comment: You are fairly close to the cylinder - I added that d must be smaller than D. It wasn't showing when I typed before. (maybe the bigger than and smaller than are special characters)

Comment: @Elric You should surround your equations with \$ \$ instead of ` `. I've edited your question to a better format.

Comment: @Elric Is the distance d from the center of the cylinder to the camera, or from the nearest point of the cylinder to the camera?

Comment: @gowrath d is from the nearest point of cylinder to the camera (was eating lunch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: camera_cylinder]

With ref. to the sketch, applying the Law of Sines
$$
\frac{{\sin \left( {\alpha \backslash 2} \right)}}
{{D/2}} = \frac{{\sin \left( {\pi  - \left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right)\backslash 2} \right)}}
{{D/2 + d}} = \frac{{\sin \left( {\left( {\alpha  + \beta } \right)\backslash 2} \right)}}
{{D/2 + d}}
$$
hence:
$$
\beta  = 2\arcsin \left( {\left( {1 + \frac{{2d}}
{D}} \right)\sin \left( {\alpha \backslash 2} \right)} \right) - \alpha \quad \left| \begin{gathered}
  \;\alpha _{\,\max }  = 2\arcsin \left( {1/\left( {1 + \frac{{2d}}
{D}} \right)} \right) \hfill \\
  \;\beta _{\,\max }  = \pi  - \alpha _{\,\max }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
where $\alpha _{\,\max }$ and $\beta _{\,\max }$ are the angles corresponding to the tangent line (indicated in red in the picture): for a larger aperture the portion of the cylinder portrayed remains the same, with some background added.

---

*Check with the solution provided by @gowrath*
The solution above coincides with that provided by gowrath, which in
fact , changing $\theta$ with $\beta$, can be further developed as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \left( {1 + \frac{{2d}}
{D} - \cos \frac{\beta }
{2}} \right)\tan \frac{\alpha }
{2} = \sin \frac{\beta }
{2} \hfill \\
  \left( {1 + \frac{{2d}}
{D} - \cos \frac{\beta }
{2}} \right)\sin \frac{\alpha }
{2} = \sin \frac{\beta }
{2}\cos \frac{\alpha }
{2} \hfill \\
  \left( {1 + \frac{{2d}}
{D}} \right)\sin \frac{\alpha }
{2} = \sin \frac{\beta }
{2}\cos \frac{\alpha }
{2} + \cos \frac{\beta }
{2}\sin \frac{\alpha }
{2} = \sin \left( {\frac{{a + \beta }}
{2}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: I already have $\alpha$, I can exchange lenses, but to me it's easier to change $d$. I want to find $n$, where $n$ is the maximum number of photos without overlapping. Your drawing is correct and allow to know the biggest angular aperture I can buy and have gains, it's just not really the question.

Comment: No, actually that is an expression for $\beta$ = the angle of the cylinder circumference which is caught in the photo, as a function of $\alpha$ (the aperture, I suppose is that) and of $d/D$.  (Suppose the sketch is clear). Then of course $\left\lfloor {2\pi /\beta } \right\rfloor $ will give you the max. number of photos you can take before overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the diameter of the cylinder, $d$ the distance of the camera from the outer edge of the cylinder, $\alpha$ is the aperture of the camera, and $\theta$ is the angle of the sector of the circle that joins the maximum coverage of the aperture at one point. I know that's wordy but a diagram should explain:

So $\theta = ADC$.

[image]

If you can find $\theta$, you can find the length of the sector $ADC$ and divide the circumference by that to get the number of unique photos.

We know length

$$
AC = \left(d+\frac{D}{2}\left(1-\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)\right)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \frac{D}{2}\left(\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\right) \\
\left(\frac{2d}{D} + 1-\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
$$

You can rearrange the above to solve for $\theta$. Thank you @GCab for the suggestion on how to proceed with the simplification. If you want to see what a tired man's approach to maths can be, check out the edits :P

$$
\left(\frac{2d}{D} + 1-\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
\left(\frac{2d}{D} + 1-\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\right)\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \\
\left(\frac{2d}{D} + 1\right)\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}\\
\left(\frac{2d}{D} + 1\right)\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \sin{\left(\frac{\theta + \alpha}{2}\right)}\\
\theta = 2\arcsin{\left(\left(\frac{2d}{D} + 1\right)\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\right)} - \alpha \\
$$

Once you have $\theta$, you ca get the number of unique pictures, $n$, by dividing the circumference by $\frac{D}{2}\theta$ and take the floor function of it:

$$
n = \left\lfloor\frac{2\pi}{\theta}\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: $D/2$ can be different than $d$, so your drawing is not correct.

Comment: Looking your calculations though, I think you are correct. I have to test.

Comment: $AC$ **is not** $ = \left(d-\frac{D}{2}\right)\tan{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ : apart from a factor $2$, you are missing to consider the segment $D/2(1-cos(\theta /2))$

Comment: @Elric Ah I responded before you replied about what d was. I took it to be the distance from the center of the circle. Will fix when I get home.

Comment: @GCab You are correct; I have updated the diagram but haven't completed solving for theta. Do check it over if you get a chance.

Comment: @gowrath, now your derivation is ok, and comparing it with the one I provided suggested me the way how yours could be further expanded, thus providing a crosscheck for both (see addendum to my post): +1 also to your job!

Comment: @GCab I think I went a little too wild. In theory, that is correct (hopefully) but I like the way you did it much more :p I just thought I would finish what I started.

Comment: @gowrath, p.s.: I so right now your continuation: allow me (just for my age) to give you a hint, before you follow a "hard" way, spend a little time to look for better ones.

Comment: @GCab Thanks for the age old wisdom - all fixed. Solutions match (y). I'm going to sleep :)